# How do I fix an input error in Python 3 for a function?

Tags: python, python-3.x, function

How does one fix

```
 error on input []: name 'xxx' is not defined
```

in their code? I am pretty sure I defined 'abcxyz' correctly so not sure how to solve this.

Comment: Why don't you want to post code? Is your code super secret government work or something?

Comment: I think I might know where your issue is. You are probably trying to access the variable that hasn't been defined yet. However, it is almost impossible to say that for sure without seeing any code. Pls update your question with it

Comment: As everybody says, we can help you more if you provide at least an example of how the code looks like. But that kind of issues are related to variables that hasn't been defined yet.

Comment: @Alex.Kh I added the relevant code. No it's not secret or anything.

Comment: @C245 Okay, thx for that. Unfortunately, this doesn't tell me a lot. If you say that you are sure you had defined `abcxyz`, where is the exact line of the code that does it? To me, it looks that the definition is not included in the function you posted.

Comment: @Alex.Kh Oops I used `abcxyz` as a neutral example before I added the actual code in. `abcxyz` in this instance of my code is `count_2`.

Comment: @C245. Hmm, then if it is complaining about `count_2` I don't see any particular reason for that. Can you edit your answer with the exact error then? Hopefully It helps

Comment: @Alex.Kh Added the error and the question text.

Comment: @C245 I wish I could see the issue straight away, but I don't. `count_2` should be defined in this scope, so I actually don't see any issues with it. However, consider thinking about your input. I am a little bit curious about `error on input []` part here. It indicates that the issue might be related to the input rather than the function itself

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you have an indentation issue. Your variable definitions are inside a function that never gets called, while the rest of your code is in the global scope, and is executed immediately when this module is loaded. Thus it has no access to the variables `count_*`.

Something like this might be more in line with your original intentions...

```py
import csv
def internet_histogram():
    count_6 = 0
    count_5 = 0
    count_4 = 0
    count_3 = 0
    count_2 = 0
    count_1 = 0
    with open("survey.csv",'r') as f:
        reader = csv.reader(f)
        with open("histogram.csv", 'w') as g:
            writer = csv.writer(g)
            next(reader)
            for line in reader:
                if int(line[3]) >= 30 and int(line[3]) <= 33:
                    if int(line[0]) == 2:
                        count_6 +=1
                    if line[2] != '':
                        if int(line[2]) == 1:
                            count_1 += 1
                        elif int(line[2]) == 2:
                            count_2 += 1
                        elif int(line[2]) == 3:
                            count_3 += 1
                        elif int(line[2]) == 4:
                            count_4 += 1
                        elif int(line[2]) == 5:
                            count_5 += 1
            arr = [[1, count_1], [2, count_2], [3, count_3], [4, count_4], [5, count_5], [6, count_6]]
            for i in arr:
                writer.writerow(i)
```

Don't forget to call `internet_histogram()` somewhere if you need this to run as a script.